# I cant access file directory with PHP local host on XAMPP. it just shows one of the files I have in my visual studio code

Tags: php, apache, directory, xampp, localhost

I am trying to access my file directory so I can access my files in the browser with php using XAMPP, but it just shows one of the pages I have in visual studio code.

I write "localhost/{filename}" in the browser, but only one page shows up and I expect the file directory to show up. I would like to access all my files in one place.